# BigQuery: Export data into hierarchical folders: YYYY/MM/DD

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a date-partitioned table in BigQuery that I'd like to export.  I would like to export it such that the data from each day ends up in a different file.  For example, to a GS bucket with a nested folder structure like  `gs://my-bucket/YYYY/MM/DD/`.  Is this possible?

Please don't tell me I need to run a separate export job for each day of data: I know this is possible but it is painful when exporting many years worth of data, as you need to run thousands of export jobs.

On the import side, this is possible with the parquet format.

If this is not possible with BigQuery directly, is there a GCS tool like dataproc or dataflow that would make this easy (bonus points for linking to a script that actually performs this export).

Comment: Do you have some example code that you are currently using to export a single table?

Comment: It looks like BigQuery doesn't support this at the moment so I've created a feature requests [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143091685).  If you're interested in this feature, please start it.

Comment: @Ben P I posted the code I've used to do this in the past below.

Answer (score 1):

Would a bash script with [bq extract](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_extract) work?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Stop on first error
set -e;

# Used for Bigquery partitioning (to distinguish from bash variable reference)
DOLLAR="\$"

# -I ISO DATE
# -d FROM STRING
start=$(date -I -d 2019-06-01) || exit -1
end=$(date -I -d 2019-06-15)   || exit -1

d=${start}

# string(d) <= string(end)
while [[ ! "$d" > "$end" ]]; do
    YYYYMMDD=$(date -d ${d} +"%Y%m%d")
    YYYY=$(date -d ${d} +"%Y")
    MM=$(date -d ${d} +"%m")
    DD=$(date -d ${d} +"%d")

    # print current date
    echo ${d}

    cmd="bq extract --destination_format=AVRO \
    'project:dataset.table${DOLLAR}${YYYYMMDD}' \
    'gs://my-bucket/${YYYY}/${MM}/${DD}/part*.avro'
    "

    # execute    
    eval ${cmd}

    # d++
    d=$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")
done
```

Maybe you should request a new feature at  https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654.

Not a bash ninja, so sure that there is a cooler way to compare dates.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestions, but as I noted in the question, I've already got a solution that solves this by kicking of lots of daily export jobs.  The issue there is that when you kick of thousands of these you need to monitor each one and run them in parallell, which is more complexity than the average user would like to deal with.I've created a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143091685).

Comment: At the moment it is not possible, as you said you can choose between sequential with a stop on the first error mode (my solution) or parallel with monitoring/logging using `-sync,--[no]synchronous_mode` mode (probably default flag using API).

Answer (score 0):

At @Ben P's request here's the solution (a python script) I've used previously to run lots of export jobs in parallel.  This is pretty rough code and should be improved by checking the status of each export job after it runs to see whether it succeeded.

I won't accept this an an answer because the question is looking for a bigquery-native way of performing this task.

Note that this script was for exporting a versioned dataset, so there's a bit of extra logic around that which many users may not need.  It assumes that the input table and output folder names both use the version.  This should be easy to strip out.

```
import argparse
import datetime as dt
from google.cloud import bigquery
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random
import time

GCS_EXPORT_BUCKET = "YOUR_BUCKET_HERE"
VERSION = "dataset_v1"

def export_date(export_dt, bucket=GCS_EXPORT_BUCKET, version=VERSION):
    table_id = '{}${:%Y%m%d}'.format(version, export_dt)
    gcs_filename = '{}/{:%Y/%m/%d}/{}-*.jsonlines.gz'.format(version, export_dt, table_id)
    gcs_path = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket, gcs_filename)
    job_id = export_data_to_gcs(table_id, gcs_path, 'currents')
    return (export_dt, job_id)

def export_data_to_gcs(table_id, destination_gcs_path, dataset):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
    job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
    job_config.destination_format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'
    job_config.compression = 'GZIP'
    job_id = 'export-{}-{:%Y%m%d%H%M%S}'.format(table_id.replace('$', '--'),
                                                dt.datetime.utcnow())
    # Add a bit of jitter
    time.sleep(5 * random.random())
    job = bigquery_client.extract_table(table_ref,
                                        destination_gcs_path,
                                        job_config=job_config,
                                        job_id=job_id)
    print(f'Now running job_id {job_id}')
    time.sleep(50)
    job.reload()
    while job.running():
        time.sleep(10)
        job.reload()
    return job_id



if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-s', "--startdate",
                        help="The Start Date - format YYYY-MM-DD (Inclusive)",
                        required=True,
                        type=dt.date.fromisoformat)
    parser.add_argument('-e', "--enddate",
                        help="The End Date format YYYY-MM-DD (Exclusive)",
                        required=True,
                        type=dt.date.fromisoformat)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    start_date = args.startdate
    end_date = args.enddate

    dates = []
    while start_date < end_date:
        dates.append(start_date)
        start_date += dt.timedelta(days=1)

    with Pool(processes=30) as pool:
        jobs = pool.map(export_date, dates, chunksize=1)
```

To run this code, put it into a file called `bq_exporter.py` and then run `python bq_exporter.py -s 2019-01-01 -e 2019-02-01`.  That'll export January of 2019, and print each of the export job's IDs.  You can check on the status of a job using BigQuery CLI via `bq show -j JOB_ID`.